# How to implement CursorList template Class in C++?

Tags: c++

I am quite a beginner at C++ and I'm facing a problem about a general template List.
I want to implement the following interface *CursorList* that organizes Objects into a list where instead of using standard list pointers I have an array of predetermined size where the first entry is the Pointer to the element itself, entry 2 is the Pointer to the next element and entry 3 is the Pointer to the previous element.

The array itself has two pointers, one points to the first Data and one to the first free spot. [This picure shows how the array should be structured.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqWh7.png)

```
template <class T> class List {
public:
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef ListIterator<T> iterator;

  bool empty() const;
  int size() const;
  T& front() const;
  void push_front(const T &); 
  void pop_front();  

  iterator begin() const;
  iterator end() const;
  iterator insert(iterator itr, const T& value);
  iterator erase(iterator start, iterator stop);
  iterator erase(iterator itr);               
 };
```

Now how would I go about doing this?

I can't use regular List methods and instead need to build and manage the array fully indepentendly. The List is supposed to work for Objects of any kind, but in this specific case it's for *Student* Objects, where the constructor looks like this:

```
Student::Student(char *name, char *preName, char *birthDate) {
    std::strncpy(this->name, name, sizeof(this->name)-1);
    this->name[sizeof(this->name)-1] = '\0';
    std::strncpy(this->preName, preName, sizeof(this->preName)-1);
    this->preName[sizeof(this->preName)-1] = '\0';
    std::strncpy(this->birthDate, birthDate, sizeof(this->birthDate)-1);
    this->birthDate[sizeof(this->birthDate)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Other than that the class just some standard setters and getters.

I'm unsure of how to define the Array and how to  implement the indivdual methods so I think what would help me most is a super simple example implementation for one of the methods. From there I should be able to figure out how to apply this structure to the other methods.

Comment: Please show the work you've already written so far, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results. You have to show your work first, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. Noone on stackoverflow.com will write an entire program (or a part of one), in reply to this type of a question. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  I have added the some of the previous work. I'm not looking for an entire program, not even part of one, just for a super simple example for one of the methods, as that would allow me to figure out the rest on my own. I can't explain how my program doesn't work if I'm completly unsure how to even get started on it.

Comment: "an array of predetermined size where the first entry is the Pointer to the element itself, entry 2 is the Pointer to the next element and entry 3 is the Pointer to the previous element." Is this an exact quite from your assignment? Linked lists are not normally done this way. Not in C++ at any rate.